# How to set up pycsw on xampp (win7)?

Tags: python, apache, csw

I'm trying to setting up pycsw on xampp.

In the pycsw's default.cfg I've the following configuration:

```
[server]
home=C:\Users\masa\xampp-201405\htdocs\pycsw
url=http://localhost:8000/pycsw/csw.py
...
[repository]
# sqlite
database=sqlite:///C:\\Users\\masa\\xampp-201405\\htdocs\\pycsw\\tests\\suites\\cite\\data\\records.db
...
```

When I start the **csw.wsgi** and go to the address `localhost:8000/?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetCapabilities` then I get the following error:

```
Could not load repository (local): (OperationalError) unable to open database file None None
```

I think the problem is caused by the insufficent permisions configure on apache . I added to **httpd.conf** the following lines:

```
<Location /pycsw/>
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
Allow from all
AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Location>

<Directory "C:/Users/masa/xampp-201405/htdocs/pycsw">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But I get the same error.

Can you give me any advice?? I'm not fluent about apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The exception report means that the database could not be found.  I'm guessing it's the SQLAlchemy connection URL syntax.

In `default.cfg`, try setting the database connection to:

`database=sqlite:////Users/masa/xampp-201405/htdocs/pycsw/tests/suites/cite/data/records.db`

Comment: Thank you Tom, but this doesn't work. This is my first experience with python&co on the server side. I've some confusion about where to perform the installation. It's inside of the `Python folder` or in the xampp `htdoc folder`? It is the same on ubuntu? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are able to see `localhost:8000/?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetCapabilities` and you are getting an XML response with `ows:ExceptionReport` then the server is working correctly and it simply can't find the SQLite db.

Comment: I'm also wondering whether this is some sort of Windows specific OS issue.  Feel free to get in touch with me if you'd like to debug deeper, and then we can report the issue/answer back here.